# value is of jsonb but expression is of type bigint error in postgresql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to migrate from oracle to postgresql.
In oracle, we have @Lob data to a field which is used to hold huge amount of data.

```
@Lob
private String A_Value;
```

For postgresql, we need to use json/jsonb in place of lob data. I have done the below changes for that.

```
@TypeDefs({
   @TypeDef(name="json", typeClass=JsonStringType.class),
   @TypeDef(name="jsonb", typeClass=JsonBinaryType.class)
 
})
public class AbcM implements Serializable{
---------
@Type(type="jsonb")
@Column(name="A_Value", columnDefinition="jsonb")
private String A_Value;
}

@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JPARepository<AuditM,Long>{}

##Impl class to save data
@Override
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> saveRequest(AbcM model){
    ARepository.saveAndFlush(model);
}
```

##ERROR: column A_Value is of type jsonb but expression is of type bigint
rewrite or cast the expression

Could you please suggest what should I do to save the data without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the postgres function `to_jsonb()` to return the bigint as jsonb.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(jsonb_col)
VALUES(to_jsonb(12345))
```